# Oracle: How do I display DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument for debugging?

Tags: oracle, xmldom

Running Oracle 10g, Sqldeveloper 1.5.5

I want to view the contents of an DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument as a string in the output or results window in sqldeveloper. or some other simple way to debug this thing...

Thanks,P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOBUFFER  Writes the contents of the node to a buffer.
DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOCLOB    Writes the contents of the node to a CLOB.
DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOFILE    Writes the contents of the node to a file.
```

I have PL/SQL code that wites it to the file system using a DIRECTORY:

```
   dbms_xmldom.writeToFile(dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument( xmldoc)
                                       ,'DATAPUMPDIR/myfile.xml') ;
```

I have created a function using dbms_xmldom.writetoclob

```
   create or replace function xml2clob (xmldoc XMLType) return CLOB is
     clobdoc CLOB := ' ';
   begin
     dbms_xmldom.writeToClob(dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument( xmldoc)
                                       ,clobdoc) ;
     return clobdoc;
   end;
   /
```

Query:

```
SELECT xml2clob(Sys_Xmlagg(
         Xmlelement(Name "dummy"
                   ,dummy
                   ),Xmlformat('dual')))
   FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dual>
  <dummy>X</dummy>
</dual>
```

You could try using a function like this:

```
   create or replace function dom2clob (domdoc  DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument) return CLOB is
     clobdoc CLOB := ' ';
   begin
     dbms_xmldom.writeToClob(domdoc,clobdoc) ;
     return clobdoc;
   end;
   /
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish the same as in:

```
"SELECT xml2clob(Sys_Xmlagg(Xmlelement(Name "dummy",dummy),Xmlformat('dual'))) FROM dual;"
```

with:

```
SELECT 
    Sys_Xmlagg(Xmlelement(Name "dummy",dummy)
    ,Xmlformat('dual')).Extract('/*').getClobVal()  as "test"
FROM dual;
```

and you do not have to create the function "xml2clob"

`.Extract('/*')` is for "pretty printing"

output:

```
<dual>   
  <dummy>X</dummy> 
</dual>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an xmltype simply use the function getClobVal()

```
xmldoc.getClobVal()
```

This returns your XMLType as a clob without the additional function overhead.